# Adapting pen of animated social media icons into prod

Tags: html, css, browser

I’m trying to implement some animated social media icons on my site with pure CSS and no JS. The pen I found that am trying to adapt is called "[Yet Another Set of Animated Social Icons](https://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/YXzXPr)".

The problem is, rectangle glyphs are showing instead of the correct social media icons in my web browser locally and remotely. The icons appear properly in the original codepen. But somewhere along the way in my implementation on my web server or in my web browser, I am importing the web fonts incorrectly.

Here is what it looks like [locally in my web browser](https://imgur.com/Ds13WWR).

So you can see it yourselves, here it is on my web-server: https://angeles4four.info/

The author of the original codepen uses external style sheets and preprocessors. I’ve done my best to include these imported in my HTML and CSS. See below.

In my head tags in my index.html is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700" rel="stylesheet">
```

In my css file is this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
 font-family: 'icomoon';
 src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/icomoon.eot?3qkin2");
 src: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/icomoon.eot?#iefix3qkin2") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/icomoon.woff?3qkin2") format("woff"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/icomoon.ttf?3qkin2") format("truetype"), url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/icomoon.svg?3qkin2#icomoon") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
```

Is this set up correctly? What am I missing? I'm trying to get my social media icons to render properly (as they appear in the original pen) instead of empty rectangle glyphs.

Comment: Your browser is probably blocking the externally loaded font files when opening the html file directly in your browser, for security reasons. Use a local development server instead.

Comment: If my web-browser was blocking externally loaded fonts when opening index.html locally, then my code hosted remotely should render as expected (like in the author's original Pen).  The problem is present remotely as well (not just locally), as you can see for yourself at the link I included above (www.angeles4four.info). The problem is also present in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Working perfectly fine under your URL in Firefox Desktop and chrome mobile...

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. You are right. I see it working in Firefox now but not Chrome: https://imgur.com/WayDLlx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap how I got this working, I made two changes:

1. Courtesy of **Hossam Elmasrey**, I added `https:` to one of the link elements in index.html.
2. Turns out I was missing local system fonts. So with Manjaro being my local O/S, I invoked: `sudo pacman -Ss ttf-liberation`. I’m not sure when, how, or why these fonts were missing, but Liberation fonts are installed now.

Then I restarted my browser. When accessing my remote website through Firefox and Chrome, all the icons load properly. Hooray! But loading index.html from Chrome and Firefox directly from my local file tree doesn’t work - - which **Connum** explained is because web browsers disable some content from loading externally for security reasons. Going forward I will use [a local testing server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server).

Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot add

> https:

try this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I added https: to that link element in my index.html however the problem persists. I've updated my initial question to reflect this.